# Accessing a Nested Json and Mapping to Frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling through an API request which is a nested response. Please see the following response example:

```
    "results": [
        {
            "company": {
                "display_name": "HAYS",
                "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
            },
            "id": "3057817031",
            "category": {
                "tag": "admin-jobs",
                "label": "Admin Jobs",
                "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
            },
            "description": "3 Month Contract available| $30-$33 per hour  Super |Full-Time Office Hours based in South Melbourne Your new company An excellent opportunity has become available for a Data Analyst / Administrator to join this manufacturing organisation in their South Melbourne office. Your new role Daily financial reporting (Excel  VLookups / Pivot Tables) Organising customer presentations on PowerPoint General Administration Data Analysis duties Tracking back orders within the warehouse Financial duties (bu…",
            "salary_is_predicted": "0",
            "redirect_url": "https://www.adzuna.com.au/land/ad/3057817031?se=pH90OV3i7BGryyzFGu5MPQ&utm_medium=api&utm_source=627be40a&v=FEB87A947F7D884DC5FF3AF7949D809733A0AA43",
            "title": "Data Analyst / Administrator",
            "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Job",
            "location": {
                "display_name": "Melbourne CBD, Melbourne",
                "area": [
                    "Australia",
                    "Victoria",
                    "Melbourne Region",
                    "Melbourne",
                    "Melbourne CBD"
                ],
                "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
            },
            "contract_time": "full_time",
            "created": "2022-04-16T17:33:31Z",
            "adref": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoicEg5ME9WM2k3QkdyeXl6Rkd1NU1QUSIsImkiOiIzMDU3ODE3MDMxIn0.94BaxIfPNOv0QowtSPt1IdwSX0XgU1GtZ9O6MohICTg"
        }
```

The following above indicates 1 singular post in a list.

I have linked this to a fetchJobs operation called 'jobs', and if I do a console.log(jobs.results), I received an array of 10 items, assorted from 0,1,2,3 -> onward to 10.
This as discussed, is the 10 jobs. https://gyazo.com/1bc435e7784efe427a2995150fd54e16

As such, I would like to access a key, any honestly to figure out how to do it, and map it to the front end or console.

For example, results.title or even results.location.area, regardless, I can't seem to access this correctly, as when I try console.log(jobs.rs

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Please let me know!
My goal is to just map these keys into a div, so if anyone could post an example, please!

Comment: Additional sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-cloud-d7iff0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data in your components [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook,
and then [map over](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) the data and render your jobs however you like.

Comment: Hi Ariel, yes I have done that already. I import this function that I have created. It is defined below here: https://gyazo.com/232965fe16ac87eb39c0a1732245c33f, sorry I can't send it all in the comment (too long)